# una expresion regular que no admita espacios al inicio y final en jsf

Tags: java, regex, jsf

Atualmente utilizo esta forma, pero no me funciona

```
<p:inputText id="nombre" placeholder="Ej. Faros" value="#{catAgrupadorMBean.agrupador.nombre}"  
    required="true" requiredMessage = "El nombre del agrupador es requerido" validatorMessage="MAL" maxlength="70" />
            <f:validateRegex pattern="[[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]*$">
            </f:validateRegex>
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]la expresión regular es:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z ]*)[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

---

1. **^[a-zA-Z0-9]** Significa que debe comenzar con un caracter numero o letra (excluye la todapoderosa ñ)

   ---
2. **([a-zA-Z ]*)** Esto es lo que tengas dento incluso espacios.

   ---
3. **[a-zA-Z0-9]$** Debe cerrar con un caracter numero o letra.

   ---

Me gustan las expresiones regulares y recomiendo esta página:

https://rubular.com

Adicionalmente he creado un ejemplo con varias palabras.

Hola He creado este enlace para aclarar las dudas:

https://rubular.com/r/tkDFYYD5FSkSPf

Comment: No olvides poner los puntos si fue útil.

Comment: muchas Gracias +

Comment: me ayudo bastante tu respuesta y usare la pagina que recomiendas

Comment: Eso es un standars que implementan la mayoría de los lenguajes.

Comment: esta expresion no acepta caracteres especiales dentro del texto, como podria aceptarlos ?

Comment: Hola puedes intentar con **[a-zA-Z[:space:]]**  en vez de [a-zA-Z ]

Comment: hola, ya lo probe como mencionas pero no funciona , si quiero agregar cualquier caracter no funciona , como se podrian aceptar mas de un caracter especial dentro del texto

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z _."]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$

Comment: Yo lo probé en esta página: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output